# Merge C# Razor syntax with jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, razor

I'm working on a project using C# razor engine and I wondering if it is possible to merge razor syntax with jQuery. Is that possible?

An approach I have done is something like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        @Html.Action("GoNext", "Actions", new { Id= ViewBag.Id, justifymessage = @:$("#msg").val(), Action = 3 })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: not 100% positive but if somebody knows I'd like to know as well. I believe the correct syntax would be to write out the html and append it somewhere w/ jQuery. something like `a href="youAction">click me</a>` and append that. I don't think you can use MVC from within jquery scripts, but I could be wrong

Comment: `@Html.Action` is server side. `$("#msg").val()` is client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Razor is server side while jQuery is client side. You can merge them... You may only write a razor code inside jQuery but razor will render it result before jQuery.

To call an action from server, use Ajax. See what you can do

```
 <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
      var url="@Url.Action("GoNext","Actions", new {Id= ViewBag.Id, Action = 3 })";
      url+="&justifymessage = "+$("#msg").val();
      jQuery.get(url).done(function(htmls){
            jQuery('#appendable').html(htmls);
       });
   });
 </script>
 <div id='appendable'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if say, you want to redirect to that url try:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var yoururl = "@Url.Action("GoNext", "Actions", new { Id= ViewBag.Id, justifymessage = "#param#", Action = 3 })";

    location.href=yoururl.replace("#param#", $("#msg").val());
});
</script>
```

Comment: the only other consideration would be the appropriate encoding of `$("#msg").val()`

Comment: do you mean `Url.Action`?? I don't think `Html.Action` will do